# DHCP for multi netwok

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I hope I well get help as I got always in this excellent forum.

We have over 120 networks (192, 172 and 10 ranges)and at the moment our DHCP server is windows server 2008, which I would like to change it to Ubuntu. How should I do that? do I have to create sub interfaces for each network and assign range to it in DHCP,conf ?

I know how to configure Ubuntu DHCP as I've configured 2 / in failover modus(Ubuntu 14.04) for our Wi-Fi system but it is only for one network.

I would like to replace the existing windows server 2008, which is serving for 120 networks with Ubuntu.

Many thanks

Madona33

Answer (score 0):

DHCP server only seeing packets on the root eth0 device and ignoring all the packets on the vlan devices

For multi network we must to create `vlan's`

Install the VLAN support package. For example, type:

```
sudo apt-get install vlan
```

Edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` file for something like this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.x.x
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast xxx.xxx.x.xxx
        network xxx.xxx.x.x

# VLAN 2
iface eth0.2 inet static
address yyy.yyy.y.y
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast yyy.yyy.y.yyy
network yyy.yyy.y.y
vlan_raw_device eth0

# VLAN 3
iface eth0.3 inet static
address zzz.zzz.z.
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast zzz.zzz.z.zzz
network zzz.zzz.z.z
vlan_raw_device eth0
```

I placed at `/etc/rc.local` to have them run after the machine boots:

```
vconfig set_flag eth0.2 1 1
vconfig set_flag eth0.3 1 1
```

The vconfig lines tell the devices that they should completely separate the packets, and treat the virtual adapters more like a real network card.

Define a subnet for each vlan, and a placeholder subnet for the root adapter just in case:

```
# Placeholder for root nic (maybe not needed?)
subnet xxx.xxx.x.x netmask 255.255.255.0 {}

# VLAN 2
subnet yyy.yyy.y.y netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option routers yyy.yyy.y.y;
        option broadcast-address yyy.yyy.y.yyy;
        pool {
                range yyy.yyy.y.yy yyy.yyy.y.yyy;
        }
}

# VLAN 3
subnet zzz.zzz.z.z netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option routers zzz.zzz.z.;
        option broadcast-address zzz.zzz.z.zzz;
        pool {
                range zzz.zzz.z.zzz zzz.zzz.z.zzz;
        }
}
```

Tell the `DHCP` server what to listen on by editing the `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` file to look something like:

```
INTERFACES="eth0.2 eth0.3"
```

restart `isc-dhcp-server` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Many thanks 2707974, that's really great. Just a question please, each network (120 networks) is a separated Vlan and managed by Cisco 3750 switches (this means we have 120 Vlans), do I still need to create the Vlans as motioned in your reply? Many thanks. Madona33

Comment: Yes, you must create 120 vlans on dhcp server. Each vlan have unique network configuration.

Comment: Hi Everyone, as I have 120 vlans and so 120 subinterfaces on eth0, is there any way to make it easier to add all subinterfaces in; /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server instead of INTERFACES="eth0.2 eth0.3 eth0.4,..,..,..eth0120"? like e.g.; INTERFACES="eth0 all" or any thing similar? as it would take ages to edit the 120 subinterfaces and it's very easy to make a mistake.  Many thanks. Madona

Comment: I see this answer is almost 8yrs old and now Ubuntu uses Netplan and has yaml configs. I am searching for an updated example